# How to concatenate user defined variables in PHP and insert result into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to concatenate three variables into one variable and INSERT the result into an MYSQL table.

Here's my code so far:

```
$title = $_GET['title']; 
$colour = $_GET['colour']; 
$shoe_id = $_GET['shoe_id'];

$order_title = $title + '(' + $colour + '|' + $shoe_id');

$sql="INSERT INTO orders(order_title_1)
VALUES('$order_title')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Result : $title ($colour | $shoe_id)
i.e. Ara Ladies Reggio Lazer Cut Trouser Shoe (White | 51179-05G) | 12200
```

At the moment the result stored in the database is zero. I presume this is because I'm using the '+' operator incorrectly, however, I'm not sure what I should be using to concatenate the variables.

What do I need to do to concatenate the variables properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Concatenate operator is . in php

Comment: Whereas `+` is used as concatenate operator in javaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way is

```
$order_title = $title .'( '.$colour.'|'.$shoe_id.' )';
```

In PHP concate operator is `.` not `+`

`+` is an arithmetic operator in PHP

Comment: Thanks! - I knew it was the incorrect operator, just wasn't sure of the right one.